# How to input string generated from linux command to variable?

Tags: linux, shell

I am facing some minor problems when coding linux shell scripts.

My codes are below and I am struggling to input my modified string names to the variable named "fileName" as shown in below. And then, I commanded echo to identify the previous code is working well. However, it outputs nothing.

How to resolve this issues?

```
for file in ./*.txt
do
fileName=$file | rev  | cut -d. -f2 | rev
     echo {$fileName}
done
```

As I said, echo{$fileName} didn't output the words that I wanted to extract.

I look forward to your helpful advice :)

Comment: To assign a modified value to `fileName`, you need something like `fileName=$(echo "$file" | rev | cut -d. -f2 | rev)`.  This echoes the value in `$file` to the sequence of commands and captures the output in the variable.  In Bash, you could use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use command substitution `$()`:

Also use `echo` to get the value of variable `file`:

```
fileName="$( echo "$file" | rev  | cut -d. -f2 | rev )"
```

Or use Here strings:

```
fileName="$( rev <<<"$file" | cut -d. -f2 | rev )"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Okay. I will do it. However, when I used my coded with awk, it didn't work.. I ran the code below in the for loop. awk '{print($2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t""0""\t""0""\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$fileName)}' $file